# unique_ptr is going out of scope within a struct

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

my code is this and in a file called uniqueptr_scope.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
#include<vector>

struct un{
    int i;
};

struct un2{
    int i;

    void testTheUN(){
        temp->i=1000;
    }

    void main2(){
        un u;
        temp = std::unique_ptr<un>(&u);
        std::cout<<temp->i<<"\n";
        testTheUN();

    }
    private:
        std::unique_ptr<un> temp;
};


int main(){


    un2 u;
    u.main2();


}
```

I compiled with this 
`g++ -std=c++1y uniqueptr_scope.cpp`

Coming to my question:
I wanted to check the scope a unique pointer within a class or struct. But when I am running the code, I am getting output as

```
-650998192
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fffd9328e40 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

so in `un2::main2()` function the temp got initialized and got assigned some value. Then when I am calling the `testTheUN()` the unique_ptr is going out of scope. As I have created a class level unique_ptr , the scope should be of the class by default.

Suppose the unique_ptr's scope is of `main2()` even then the main2 has not exited completely and thereby unique_ptr's destructor shouldn't be called!
That's what I am confused!

note: using g++ 4.8 compiler (Which is latest in Ubuntu repo) so had to give the "c++1y" std

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the lines

```
un u;
temp = std::unique_ptr<un>(&u);
```

`temp` is a `unique_ptr` that points to `&u`. After the function returns, the pointer under `temp` is a dangling pointer.

Use

```
un u;
temp = std::make_unique<un>(u);
```

instead.

Comment: @O'Neil,  that would work if the OP doesn't want to copy the value of `u`.

Comment: I am still not getting as in the stack, main2 calls the testTheUn(), temp would be still having a live reference to the `u`

Comment: @srinath29, the problem occurs when you return from `main`. At that time, `u.temp` contains a dangling pointer.

Comment: But after returning from `main2` I not using the `temp` for any other purpose. So it will not try to read the memory location which was pointed out previously

Comment: @srinath29, the destructor of `unique_ptr` will try to release the memory that the underlying pointer points to.

Comment: Oh! ok.... got it!! forgot about the destructor of unique_ptr! Which in a sense makes unique_ptr so great!! My foolishness!